# How to get data between tags in array

Tags: php, xml, regex, preg-replace

I have data between tags

```
<ml><locale name="en-US">125LKO.50C-SL137</locale>
     <locale name="es-ES"></locale>
 </ml>
```

like wise,I want to data into array in like this format

```
 arr['en']= "125LKO.50C-SL137"
 arr['es']= "-";
```

or

```
 arr['0']= "125LKO.50C-SL137"
 arr['1']= "-";
```

I am using this function

```
function get_string_between($string){
 $string = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', "~", $string);
 $words = explode('~', $string);
 return array_values(array_filter($words));
}
```

How may i get data into array in php, Please help me.

Comment: It is better to use Javascript. You should definitely use PHP?

Comment: data between tag is coming dynamically or it's simple html?

Comment: Parse the markup, and use selectors to get the nodes you want, then get the node attributes and values in any way you want them. PHP has [the `DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument) class, JavaScript has [the `DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) object. Both will do just fine

Comment: Try using http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: data come from database

Comment: @ShaunakShukla: cf the tags: XML tag in there, so the data is, presumably an XML DOM

Comment: @webdeveloper: XML + regex are a bit of a no-no... just thought you should know

Comment: My function is working fine,it is fail when one tag haven't value

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem, thanks I didn't notice that!!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll bite. Parsing XML with regex is like trying to cut down a tree with a hammer. Sure, you might eventually end up with something that looks like it works, but you'll spend too much time writing code that handles those cases where the pattern you use just doesn't quite cut it.
Markup languages, like XML or HTML are best parsed. And Luckily, PHP comes with a couple of tools that do just that: Parse markup. Just off the bat, here's how I'd process the data you have:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('ml/locale');
$result = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    $result[] = array(
        'val'        => $node->nodeValue,
        'nameAttr'   => $node->attributes->getNamedItem('name')->value
    );
}
var_dump($result);
```

As you can [see here](http://codepad.org/J1aGS4sb), it works just fine. Of course, this code isn't copy-paste ready at all, but it should be enough to get you started. Look into xpaths, and [the `DOMDocument` API](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument). It's worth the time, promise!

Just to help you a bit more, in reality, you'd check the return value of `$node->attributes->getNamedItem` first, before accessing a property on its return value, as it can return `null`:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    $attribute = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('name') ? : null;
    $result[] = array(
        'val'  => $node->nodeValue,//empty string, or node contents/value
        'name' => $attribute ? $attribute->value : null//null, or the name attribute value
    );
}
```

That would be a more reliable approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex which may not be the best solution but it would go something like:

```
<locale.*>(.*)<\/locale>
```

Test it with [regex101](http://regex101.com/#pcre) for instance, it works. 
Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) like this:

```
// $string is your DATA to search in 
$string = '<ml><locale name="en-US">125LKO.50C-SL137</locale>
   <locale name="es-ES"></locale>
   </ml>';
preg_match_all("/<locale.*>(.*)<\/locale>/", $string , $matches); // use preg_match only if searching for first occurrence only

foreach($matches[0] as $match){ 
  echo $match; // first one is en and second is es  
}
```

Dont forget: parsing xml/html with regex is usually not a good idea. Try to use dedicated  parser instead.

Comment: If there is only one occurrence of this in your text you must use preg_match without '_all' and then $matches as $match and not $matches[0]

Comment: it Works fine at this case but failed if these tags having html contnent

Comment: You didn't mention this in your question. And that is why you should use DOM parser instead :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can do this:

```
$rule = '/\<locale name\=\"([\w\.\-\_]*)\"\>([\w\.\-\_]*)\<\/locale\>/';
```

And then you do:

```
$array = array();

preg_match_all($ruke, $string, $array);
```

Comment: It gives this answer Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => en-US ) [2] => Array ( [0] => ) )

Comment: well. Please give me what you pass as the string input to the  `preg_match_all() `?

Comment: $string="<ml><locale name="en-US">125LKO.50C-SL137</locale>
     <locale name="es-ES"></locale>
 </ml>"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PHP: XmlReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) to read elements of your Xml file. A regular expression is ok and you can receive what you want with it, but if you want to be more flexible I' prefer the PHP Xml Reader class

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below PHP code,

```
<?php
$mystring = <<< 'EOT'
<ml><locale name="en-US">125LKO.50C-SL137</locale>
     <locale name="es-ES"></locale>
 </ml> 
EOT;
$regex =  '~(?m)<ml><locale\s*name="..\K-|(?<=>).+?(?=<)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $mystring, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "125LKO.50C-SL137"
  }
}
```